# jQuery function unresponsive after changing html

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

  $(".next").click(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    $('#tab_change').html('<div class="back"></div>');  
    $("#tab2").show();  
    return false;
  });

  $(".back").click(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    $('#tab_change').html('<div class="next"></div>');  
    $("#tab1").show();  
    return false;
  });
```

THe problem is that when next is clicked, the 2nd tab opens. But after the html of `#tab_change` changed, the back button is responsive. The  `$(".back").click(function() {` doesnt work.

HTML is posted for reference.

```
    <div class="dialog_content" style="width:780px">

        <div id="tab_change" class="left border_right">
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>

    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">

        <div class="right"><?php include("C:/easyphp/www/zabjournal/lib/flexpaper/php/split_document.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't destroy and rebuild the content of `'#tab_change'`. Just toggle the `back/next` class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind with the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. Since the back div doesn't exit when the DOM is loaded, you need to bind the click event to it. Change:

```
$(".back").click(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    $('#tab_change').html('<div class="next"></div>');  
    $("#tab1").show();  
    return false;
});
```

to:

```
$('body').on('click','.back', function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    $('#tab_change').html('<div class="next"></div>');  
    $("#tab1").show();  
    return false;
});
```

When you use .click() you're binding the click event to an element that exists when the DOM is loaded. However, your "back" div doesn't yet exist, so you can't bind anything to it. By using, .on(), jQuery watches the DOM to see if that element gets created and when it does, attaches the click event to it.

Comment: Yea this is basically the OPs problem since `.next` is dinamically created.

Comment: Can you explain me why I need to on.() function? Why my code didn't work.

Comment: When you bind `click()` to `.next` the element still doesn't exist that's why you need to use `on()` to apply that event to future instances of `.next`. But as **am not i am** suggested in the comments I think your approach might be a bit overkill.

Comment: Yes I have revised the code as @SKS has posted a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got too much dom operations for a simple show and hide. Try something like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/YwEKm/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  var $tab1 = $("#tab1"), $tab2 = $('#tab2');    

  $tab2.hide();
  $tab1.show(); //Show first tab

  $('#tab_change div').click (function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('next')) {
           $this
             .removeClass('next')
             .addClass('back');

           $tab1.hide();
           $tab2.show(); 
        } else {
           $this
             .removeClass('back')
             .addClass('next');

           $tab2.hide();
           $tab1.show();
        }
  });
 });
```